# Deployment of Ruby on rails application cache permission capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have deployed application using Capistrano and Passenger, I did not played with permission it is all root user doing stuff.

I have installed NGINx and passenger, everything working fine, when I deploy my application it goes smoothly and all setup. But when I browse it gives me error that I have permission issue for cache directory.

So each time when I deploy I have to give this permission again and again. Following is my Cap configuration

```
lock "~> 3.11.1"
set :application, "my_app_ame"
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:url_of_git.git"

set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/rubysites/test_production"
append :linked_files, "config/credentials.yml.enc"
append :linked_files, "config/master.key"
append :linked_files, "config/database.yml"
```

and my staging.rb file

```
set :stage, :staging
set :rails_env, :production
set :branch, "development"

server "ror.test_domain.com", user: "root", roles: %w{app db web}
```

But on each deploy I have to run command to change permissions

```
 chmod -R 777 releases/
```

Answer (score 0):

Got no response, but I have tried few things.
1. I have added following gem in my Gemfile

```
gem 'capistrano-file-permissions'
```

and than I added following in my Capfile

```
set :file_permissions_paths, ["app/logs", "app/cache"]
set :file_permissions_users, ["www-data"]
```

Unfortunately it did not work for me, I think I have incorrect understanding of files where to put these commands.

2. I used another idea where I run execute command to do file permissions. so I added following my `deploy.rb` file. I also added some rake tasks as I have to do that for some updates.

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :check_permissions do
    on roles(:web) do
      execute "chmod -R 0777 #{release_path}"
      execute "echo 'finished'"
      execute "cd #{deploy_to}/current && /usr/bin/env rake countries:update RAILS_ENV=production"
    end
  end
end
```

Voila it worked for me, and now all good, but yes I have some shortcoming on knowledge about cap files, so hope in future I will be able to improve it.